# Run Time Errors with C++ 2011 Threads

Tags: multithreading, c++11

I have the following simple program using the thread library of C++11. It compiles but does not run.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <future>
using namespace std;
double square(int i) {
 return i * i;
}

int main() {
 future<double> fd = async(square, 2);
 double d = fd.get();
 cout << d << endl;
 return 0;
}
```

Runnning the program gives

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::system_error'
  what():  Unknown error -1
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I use gcc version 4.8.2 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) and compile with  "g++ -o main3 -std=c++11 -Wall -g main3.cpp -lpthread" Has anybody a good idea what's happening there?

Comment: on g++ 4.9.1  ubuntu 14.10 it compiles/executes OK as it prints out value of   4     ..............     g++ -o threading threading.cpp  -std=c++11  -lpthread  -Wall

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to compile your program as follows:

`g++ -o main3 -std=c++11 -pthreads -Wall -g main3.cpp`

This will add support for multithreading and will set flags for preprocessor and linker. The option `-lpthread` only adds the `Pthread` library while linking and may be insufficient.

The manual page of `g++ 4.8.2` states the following:

> **-pthreads**
>
> Add support for multithreading using the POSIX threads library.
>      This option sets flags for both the preprocessor and linker.  This
>      option does not affect the thread safety of object code produced
>             by the compiler or that of libraries supplied with it.

Comment: My g++ required -pthread rather than -pthreads with s. But indeed it solved the issue. But Scott is also right, newer versions of g++ are not that sensible anymore and do the job only with -pthread, at least for this program.